# Wordpress: Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_user_logged_in()

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm loading a PHP script in a wordpress page but when the script is run I get this:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_user_logged_in()
```

Code that it tries to run:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() == true ) {
  /* Some code */
} else {
 /* Some other code */
}
?>
```

I tried searching for an answer but I couldn't find a working solution.
From what I found on the internet my script is running outside of wordpress and that's why it can't find the function.

Comment: The Internet is right, you are running outside of wordpress and that's why it can't find the function.

Comment: where are you putting that code?

Comment: @Samir in ../wp-includes/custom-scripts and I load it in via a php plugin for wordpress. And all that works fine but not this one.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps you are running the code too early as mentioned here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-is_user_logged_in

> The problem is that is_user_logged_in is a pluggable function, and is
>   therefore loaded after this plugin logic is called. The solution is to
>   make sure that you don't call this too early.

His solution was to wrap the code in another function which is called on init and can be put in your [functions.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) file:

```
function your_login_function()
{
    if ( is_user_logged_in() == true ) {
       /* Some code */
    } else {
        /* Some other code */
    }
}
add_action('init', 'your_login_function');
```

Comment: So to be clear I have to put that code in function.php and that's it? Seems to easy to be true XD

Comment: functions.php, yes. It should call on 'init' which means the function should be available then.  Before it seemed you were trying to call the function before it was set.

Comment: I get this when I try to load anything of the website: Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action() in C:\*\*\wp-includes\functions.php on line 4871

Comment: Ok, sorry man, I assumed you had a bit of experience in this.  So are you trying to build a Plugin or a Theme or something? If so, your plugin/theme should have it's own folder and inside that folder should be a functions.php file, this is your plugin/themes personal functions.php file which you can edit.  You don't want to change anything in wp-includes.

Comment: I'm not trying to make a plugin or theme (And I indeed don't have experience in 'that'). I'm trying to load a php script via a wordpress php plugin on a wordpress page. Every other script that I loaded works fine but this one doens't.

Comment: Right, but you are trying to load the script the wrong way. Wordpress is not meant to have custom scripts loaded all throughout the wp-include. Nothing in the wp-include folder is meant to be changed.  Everything custom should be in wp-content and added through a theme or a plugin. This is why you are getting the error. Some stuff will work accidentally and some stuff will not. Your best bet is to make a Plugin and include all of your scripts through that plugin: https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: You can also check out this link: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/74940/what-is-the-wordpress-wp-includes-folder-for which discusses why the wp-includes folder should never be modified.

Answer (score 0):

I've got my answer.

I needed to add this line of code to my php script:

```
require_once("path/to/wordpress/wp-load.php");
```

And that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once( wp_normalize_path(ABSPATH).'wp-load.php');

class Your_Plugin_Class {
    private  $is_user_logged_in;

    add_action('init', function(){
        $this-> is_user_logged_in = is_user_logged_in();
        echo 'is_user_logged_in'.$this->is_user_logged_in;
    });

    add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields-2',array( $this, 'add_billing_field' ));

   }

    public function add_billing_field( $fields = array() ) {
        if ( $this->is_user_logged_in  ){
            echo 'add_billing_field'.$this->is_user_logged_in;
            return $fields;
        }else{
            echo 'add_billing_field'.$this->is_user_logged_in;
        }
    }
}
```